# I want to change the blue point in Android Studio maps to arrow

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, mobile

I want to change the default icon your location in Google Maps in Android Studio to another icon.

The default icon is the blue circle and thank you.

[image]

Comment: it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Please add more details and what you have tried so far??

Comment: I Want to change the default icon in google maps the blue icon it see your location in maps

Answer (score 1):

The solution is `setMyLocationEnabled(false)` to make this circle disappear and get the last location manually by using
GoogleApiClient.

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                try {
                    lat = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                    lng = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng))                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker_red)));






                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
                super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
            }
        };
```

And in your `onConnected` method :

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(LocationActivity.this)
            .requestLocationUpdates(
                    getLocationRequest(), locationCallback, null);


}
```

where getLocationRequest:

```
private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        return mLocationRequest;
    }
```